# PHP convert string to hex and hex to string

Tags: php, string, hex

I got the problem when convert between this 2 type in PHP. This is the code I searched in google

```
function strToHex($string){
    $hex='';
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($string); $i++){
        $hex .= dechex(ord($string[$i]));
    }
    return $hex;
}


function hexToStr($hex){
    $string='';
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($hex)-1; $i+=2){
        $string .= chr(hexdec($hex[$i].$hex[$i+1]));
    }
    return $string;
}
```

I check it and found out this when I use XOR to encrypt.

I have the string `"this is the test"`, after XOR with a key, I have the result in string `↕↑↔§P↔§P ♫§T↕§↕`. After that, I tried to convert it to hex by function strToHex() and I got these `12181d15501d15500e15541215712`. Then, I tested with the function hexToStr() and I have `↕↑↔§P↔§P♫§T↕§q`. So, what should I do to solve this problem? Why does it wrong when I convert this 2 style value?

Comment: You know there are `hex2bin()` and `bin2hex()` in PHP?

Comment: *strToHex* returns a *string* of hex - so if you XOR that directly with the `^` operator, that won't give any good result. Maybe you could give *strToHex* another param being the number you want to XOR with, and XOR directly inside that function: `$hex .= dechex(ord($string[$i]) ^ $MYKEYBYTE);`

Comment: I thought that the problem is at hexToStr() function. Because when it convert to string, it pass the space or some special character, and make the problem

Comment: I tried hex2bin() and bin2hex(). It's really good and solve this. but in real situation, It doesn't. It just be right if I call bin2hex() function after encrypt by XOR the plaintext with key. But in a real situation, we usually use strToHex() after XOR , so when we decrypt by XOR the Crypt with KEY to get the plaintext, we call the hexToStr() It will get wrong result.

Answer (score 145):

For people that end up here and are just looking for the hex representation of a (binary) string.

```
bin2hex("that's all you need");
# 74686174277320616c6c20796f75206e656564

hex2bin('74686174277320616c6c20796f75206e656564');
# that's all you need
```

Doc: [bin2hex](https://www.php.net/manual/function.bin2hex.php), [hex2bin](https://www.php.net/manual/function.hex2bin.php).

Comment: what about [2's compliment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61952913/php-string-to-hex-with2s-complement)?

Comment: I made a gist that incorporated this. A simple hex dumper function for PHP: https://gist.github.com/hopeseekr/9964a9f12428dd220c3dd29a9943ce65

Answer (score 56):

For any char with ord($char) < 16 you get a HEX back which is only 1 long. You forgot to add 0 padding.

This should solve it:

```
<?php
function strToHex($string){
    $hex = '';
    for ($i=0; $i<strlen($string); $i++){
        $ord = ord($string[$i]);
        $hexCode = dechex($ord);
        $hex .= substr('0'.$hexCode, -2);
    }
    return strToUpper($hex);
}
function hexToStr($hex){
    $string='';
    for ($i=0; $i < strlen($hex)-1; $i+=2){
        $string .= chr(hexdec($hex[$i].$hex[$i+1]));
    }
    return $string;
}


// Tests
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
function test($expected, $actual, $success) {
    if($expected !== $actual) {
        echo "Expected: '$expected'\n";
        echo "Actual:   '$actual'\n";
        echo "\n";
        $success = false;
    }
    return $success;
}

$success = true;
$success = test('00', strToHex(hexToStr('00')), $success);
$success = test('FF', strToHex(hexToStr('FF')), $success);
$success = test('000102FF', strToHex(hexToStr('000102FF')), $success);
$success = test('↕↑↔§P↔§P ♫§T↕§↕', hexToStr(strToHex('↕↑↔§P↔§P ♫§T↕§↕')), $success);

echo $success ? "Success" : "\nFailed";
```

Comment: In the strToHex function, as an alternative to the whole dechex() and substr -2, one may just use: `$hex .= sprintf('%02.x', $ord);`

Comment: In case of 16 bit what should I do?

Answer (score 38):

PHP :

string to hex:

```
implode(unpack("H*", $string));
```

hex to string:

```
pack("H*", $hex);
```

Comment: You could avoid the call to implode by using `list`, ie: `list(, $hex) = unpack('H*', $string);`

Comment: The HEX value of 64 is 40. But it's returning me something else

Answer (score 13):

Here's what I use:

```
function strhex($string) {
  $hexstr = unpack('H*', $string);
  return array_shift($hexstr);
}
```

Comment: with [2's compliment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61952913/php-string-to-hex-with2s-complement)?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to convert hex to string:

```
    $s = '\x64\x65';
    $t = array_map(function($item){
        return pack("H*", $item);
    }, explode('/x', $s));
    $result = implode('', $t);
```

Answer (score 1):

I only have half the answer, but I hope that it is useful as it adds unicode (utf-8) support

```php
    /**
     * hexadecimal to unicode character
     * @param  string  $hex
     * @return string
     */
    function hex2uni($hex) { 
      $dec = hexdec($hex);
        if($dec < 128) {
            return chr($dec);
        }
        if($dec < 2048) {
            $utf = chr(192 + (($dec - ($dec % 64)) / 64));
        } else {
            $utf = chr(224 + (($dec - ($dec % 4096)) / 4096));
            $utf .= chr(128 + ((($dec % 4096) - ($dec % 64)) / 64));
        }
        return $utf . chr(128 + ($dec % 64));
    }
```

To string

```php
    var_dump(hex2uni('e641'));
```

Based on: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php#Hcom55978

Answer (score 1):

```
function hexToStr($hex){
    // Remove spaces if the hex string has spaces
    $hex = str_replace(' ', '', $hex);
    return hex2bin($hex);
}
// Test it 
$hex    = "53 44 43 30 30 32 30 30 30 31 37 33";
echo hexToStr($hex); // SDC002000173

/**
 * Test Hex To string with PHP UNIT
 * @param  string $value
 * @return 
 */
public function testHexToString()
{
    $string = 'SDC002000173';
    $hex    = "53 44 43 30 30 32 30 30 30 31 37 33";
    $result = hexToStr($hex);

    $this->assertEquals($result,$string);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using @bill-shirley answer with a little addition

```
function str_to_hex($string) {
$hexstr = unpack('H*', $string);
return array_shift($hexstr);
}
function hex_to_str($string) {
return hex2bin("$string");
}
```

Usage:

```
  $str = "Go placidly amidst the noise";
  $hexstr = str_to_hex($str);// 476f20706c616369646c7920616d6964737420746865206e6f697365
  $strstr = hex_to_str($str);// Go placidly amidst the noise
```

Comment: Why not convert the accented characters first

Comment: Any particular approach recommended? `mb_convert_encoding`? This is outside the original scope, but the hex information will be converted back into string in MSSQL, which doesn't have a decoding function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code to convert the image to hex string

```
<?php
$image = 'sample.bmp';
$file = fopen($image, 'r') or die("Could not open $image");
while ($file && !feof($file)){
$chunk = fread($file, 1000000); # You can affect performance altering
this number. YMMV.
# This loop will be dog-slow, almost for sure...
# You could snag two or three bytes and shift/add them,
# but at 4 bytes, you violate the 7fffffff limit of dechex...
# You could maybe write a better dechex that would accept multiple bytes
# and use substr... Maybe.
for ($byte = 0; $byte < strlen($chunk); $byte++)){
echo dechex(ord($chunk[$byte]));
}
}
?>
```