# How could I convert a bytes to a whole hex string?

Tags: python, redis, byte

```
a1 = b'\x01\x02\x41'
```

`\x41` is `A`

and when I print `str(a1)`, I get

```
b'\x01\x02A'
```

how could I get the original hex string?

I want to get:

```
\x01\x02\x41
```

I use this string for `redis-cli --pipe`.

I don't want python to print the converted string for me.

How could I do it?

now I do like this:

```
def convert(i:bytes):
    result = list()
    for j in i:
        result.append('\\x%s' % bytes([j]).hex())
    return ''.join(result)
```

It is too ugly.
Is there a better way?

btw.

This is my redis-cli --pipe script:

```
SET "\xda\xb8\xe6\xc0\x79\x62\xea\x06\xde\x9e\xb0\x4e\x68\xde\x0b\x62" "\x00\x42\xdc\x06\x03\x00\x00\x00"
SET "\x68\xfa\xfc\x03\x36\x99\xb0\x56\xb4\x00\xaf\x61\x42\xe0\x30\x42" "\x01\x42\xdc\x06\x03\x00\x00\x00"
SET "\x40\x98\xb9\x8f\xd8\x4e\x2e\x32\x40\x09\xca\xa4\x55\x52\xde\x7f" "\x02\x42\xdc\x06\x03\x00\x00\x00"
SET "\xd0\x75\xdf\x46\x36\xd0\xb4\xed\xcc\xed\xd6\x27\xf7\xd9\xc5\xa5" "\x03\x42\xdc\x06\x03\x00\x00\x00"
```

I use it this way:

```
cat sample.redis | redis-cli --pipe
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674834/php-convert-string-to-hex-and-hex-to-string

Comment: @Mike: Why link to that post? Is it because PHP is such a more expressive language than Python?

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you think you need to produce `\x..` escape sequences for Redis. If you are outputing to a `redis-cli --pipe` command from Python, write the binary data *directly to the pipe* (following the protocol, so `$<length>\r\n` followed by the binary data followed by `\r\n`. The Redis protocol itself doesn't have any `\x..` escape sequence support, and value of the `bytes` object is *not any different* just because the `repr()` of the value uses ASCII characters for bytes that happen to be ASCII codepoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When iterating over a `bytes` value, you get integers; these are trivially converted to hex notation:

```
def convert(value: bytes):
    return ''.join([f'\\x{b:02x}' for b in value])
```

Note that this produces a string with *literal backslashes, `x` characters and hexadecimal digit characters*. It is no longer a `bytes` value.

Demo:

```
>>> print(convert(b'\x01\x02\x41'))
\x01\x02\x41
```

Just to make sure, you *do not need to worry about the `bytes` value*. The `repr()` representation of a `bytes` object will always use ASCII characters when the byte value happens to be that of a printable ASCII codepoint. That doesn't mean the value is changed. `b'\x01\x02\x41'` is equal to `b'\x01\x02A'`. The Redis protocol doesn't know anything about `\x<HH>` escape sequences, so don't try to send the above string over the wire.

The escape sequences you produce are [*bash shell string sequences*](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings), and just like Python strings, you *don't have to use escapes*. As in Python, to Bash the strings `"\x01\x02A"` and `"\x01\x02\x41"` have equal values. They only make sense when you are passing in the key and value strings on the command line, not in a text file you pipe to `redis-cli`.

Moreover, please note that the `redis-cli --pipe` command takes **raw Redis protocol input**, not Redis command syntax, see the [*Redis Mass Insertion* documentation](https://redis.io/topics/mass-insert). This protocol does *not* use `\xhh` sequences, as it does not use shell notation.

Instead, use the following function to generate raw `SET` commands:

```
def raw_protocol(cmd: str, *args: bytes):
    return b'\r\n'.join([
        f'*{len(args) + 1}\r\n${len(cmd)}\r\n{cmd}'.encode(),
        *(bv for a in args for bv in (b'$%d' % len(a), a)),
        b''
    ])
```

For a `SET` command, use `raw_protocol('SET', keybytes, valuebytes)` and write out the binary data this produces to a file opened in binary mode.

Comment: Thank you! I use this in python 3.6: return ''.join(['\\x%02x' % b for b in value])

Comment: @JianDai: the code I posted works perfectly fine in Python 3.6. I'm not sure why you changed it; the `f'...'` formatted string literal syntax is a lot faster than using the older printf-style formatting operation.

Comment: You are right. I just know, I thought it was a feature in python3.7. :) Study a lot from you, Thank you.

Comment: @JianDai: note that I still don't think you are using the redis pipe feature correctly.

Comment: yes. finally I give up this way. At first I think it will reduce the space in binary key. But Finanally I found redis can compress my txt data better than binary data, and when in unicode, it is easy to use too.

Comment: got a dump from redis-cli that was a mish mash of bytes and characters. c# failed me, but python b'/x00U...' totally recognized it this post was super helpful.