# Parse hexadecimal data from txt.file in PHP

Tags: php

I have a text file with some hexadecimal data inside.

I can open it in PHP, and output a full line on the webpage, but i want to parse this result into different lines

```
<?php

$file_handle = fopen("result.txt", "rb");    
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
    $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
    $parts = explode('=', $line_of_text);
    print $parts[0] . $parts[1]. "<BR>";
}

fclose($file_handle);
```

This reads the txt. file and it displays on the web page the following data

> 20d73ef83df97d721c14c4340f45fae151b4

but i need to parse this result to something like this displayed in text boxes

> Key1 = 20D7
>   Message ciphered = 73EF83DF97D7
>   IV = 21C14C4340
>   Result key = F45FAE151B4

and so on until it finishes parsing last bytes, some lines have bigger length then others.

Comment: If the input is always formed like so you could use `substr()` to initially grab the relevant portions, then de-hex the results with like fashion this SO thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674834/php-convert-string-to-hex-and-hex-to-string

Comment: please [edit] your question to provide comments as to what your code does.

Comment: You have an error in the  displayed data or your expected result is incorrect: 20d**7**3

Comment: Nobody will be able to tell you what's wrong without seeing your text file.

Answer (score 0):

The function [sscanf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php) can be used to split a string. The exact number of characters must be known for each part.

Example:

```
$string = '20d773ef83df97d721c14c4340f45fae151b4';
list($Key1, $Message_ciphered, $IV, $Result_key) = sscanf($string, "%4s%12s%10s%10s");
```

List was used here to show that sscanf provides an array here.
[File](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) can be used To read a file line by line into an array.