# SQL and PHP: Is it possible to convert a string to binary without using SQL function

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a code like this:

```sql
CONVERT(binary, 'Hello World!')
```

Is it possible to convert that into pure php code?

This trick didn't work:

```php
$data = (binary) 'Hello World!';
```

I want the output similar to this:

```
0x316B646A666762663100000000
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP convert string to hex and hex to string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14674834/2029983)

Comment: I tried many of them and none work.

Comment: You can run shell command via php and use mysql -e option in CLI for execute deisred function or procedure

Comment: *"I tried many of them and none work. "* then post your attempts and explain why they didn't work and/or the error you received.

Comment: @Larnu I did some experiment and I guess the string to hex conversion login on the given link works but I'll have to add 0x as prevalue and the output should be exactly 28 characters so I'll have to add 0 as postvalue until it reaches the 28 characters. Thank you.

Comment: Like the output is `696E6A656C30323130` and I'll have to add `0x` as prevalue and `00000000` as postvalue for it to match the 28 characters. so basically the final output would be `0x696E6A656C3032313000000000`

Comment: @larnu you can add an answer and I'll approve it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If the above answered your question, I'll flag as a duplicate, as there's no benefit to me answering the qusetion when it's already answered. INstead upvote the answer (and question) of the duplicate. :)