# file_exists can't find filename including ampersand on Linux

Tags: php, file-exists, ampersand

I have two files: one called `AB.txt`, the other called `A&B.txt`. For each, I run the following PHP code:

```
echo "[$arq]";
if (file_exists($arq)) {
    echo '[found]';
} else {
    echo '[none]';
}
```

The outputs are `[AB.txt] [found]` and `[A&B.txt] [none]`.

I tried replacing the `&` with `\&` inside `file_exists()`, but it also doesn't work. And it doesn't seem to be a (lack of) UTF-8 problem.

Why is that? I'm on a Linux (Debian 11) machine, using PHP 7.4.

EDIT

```
var_dump(scandir('.'));
```

Returns hundreds of files (they're on a subdirectory, actually, but let's pretend they're not). I've removed all the other files from the list bellow.

> array(352) { [302]=> string(7) "A&B.txt" [303]=> string(6) "AB.txt" }

EDIT 2

```
var_dump($f = "diffA&B.txt", file_exists($f), touch($f), file_exists($f));
```

> string(11) "diffA&B.txt" bool(false) bool(true) bool(true)

Comment: How do you set the value for `$arq`? What is the output of `var_dump($arq);` when you use the filename `A&B.txt`?

Comment: @Progman $arq comes from $_POST. var_dump gives `string(7) "A&B.txt"`

Comment: try to use scandir method and check the existance with in_array()

Comment: @KhaledHassan Thank you. I can use glob too, but I want to find out why file_exists doesn't work here.

Comment: @Rodrigo Please [edit] your question to include the output of `var_dump($f = "diffA&B.txt", file_exists($f), touch($f), file_exists($f));` to your question. Be careful with the filename here, I used a different one so it is not in a conflict with your current file, but for obvious reason, it should still contain a `&`. Delete any such file before running the new code (any followup execution will return `true` for the first `file_exists()`).

Comment: @Progman Edited. Strangely, now it recognizes the newly created file.

Comment: I just tried this and it worked fine. Are you on Unix or Windows?

Comment: @Rodrigo Check the bytes in the string `$arq` and check the bytes of the array entry `[302]` from the `scandir('.')` call, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14674834/php-convert-string-to-hex-and-hex-to-string

Comment: The more pertinent question is: What OS are you using, and what filesystem are these files on?

Comment: @Barmar Linux (Debian 11). It's on the question.

Comment: @Sammitch Linux (Debian 11). It's on the question. The filesystem is Ext4 (version 1.0).

Comment: @Progman `A&B.txt` is not the real filename. I just used it to simplify things. `bin2hex("A&B.txt")` returns `4126422e747874`, with `26` as the hex for `&`. While the real file name (in `$arq`) returns `26616d703b` in the place where the `&` is. `hex2bin('26616d703b')` returns `&amp;`, which appears as a single `&` under `echo`, etc. So it seems you pinpointed the source of it. Thank you!

Comment: @Progman Problem solved. I was using `.innerHTML` before submitting the form (thus `&` became `&amp;`), where I should use `.innerText`.

Comment: @Rodrigo For the future: Do not change any requested debug information. The `var_dump()` line shows the length and content of a string and if you have showed the real output, it would be easily visible that the string length does not match the visible string content.